# Capture http request using postman (Postman interceptor does not pass http request data to postman)

Tags: postman, interceptor

I followed up the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBjXVrS8nXs after enable interceptor.

But I could not find http request in postman History tab ( v7.12.0 is the latest version.).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With google postman team help, following extension needs to be installed.

1. Install postman interceptor and enable it in chrome
   [image]
2. Enable  postman interceptor in postman app side.
   it still show "INTERCEPTOR DISCONNECTED"
   [image]
3. Installing the [Interceptor Bridge](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor-extension/#installing-the-interceptor-bridge) and restart chromes
   "INTERCEPTOR CONNECTED"
   [image]